Toilet hissing even after shutoff turned off
We've got a house that's about 40 years old. We've been here for a bit over 20 years. We've got a toilet in a big closet right off of our laundry room. It's weird. We seldom ever use it as that closet is used for storage and often has stuff on it.
This afternoon I walked in to get some paper towels and it sounded like the toilet was running. I opened the lid and I could see water moving in the bowl. Figured the flapper was bad so I shut the water off with the valve (old full/many turns to close). I don't see water coming out anymore from the fill valve but it is making a hissing sound and I hear what sounds like dripping sound occasionally. The hiss is pretty loud. The fill valve is those Korky style that you can get at Lowes.
I'm pretty troubled that it is making this sound. The toilet shares a wall with our garage so I went out to check for leaks and don't see any. Our house is on a slab but garage is lower (step up to get in the house).
I will call a plumber tomorrow but concerned that though I didn't see it we may have water leak in the wall. Is it possible that the shutoff valve has failed and the hiss I'm hearing is the shutoff valve being mostly closed but not closed enough that it is allowing a little water into the tank (the occasional drip I hear but don't see)?

Does the tank fill up when the external valve is closed? If not, your hissing is from somewhere else.

The seals in those valves harden over time. It may not be closing all the way. Can you do some basic troubleshooting?

This is quite possible:

Is it possible that the shutoff valve has failed and the hiss I'm hearing is the shutoff valve being mostly closed but not closed enough that it is allowing a little water into the tank (the occasional drip I hear but don't see)?

Old-style valves, like this several-turns valve, can go bad just sitting there and not being turned for several years. The rubber seals inside get brittle and degrade, and fall apart when the valve is finally turned.
The newer-style quarter-turn valves hold up better. If plumbing is not your thing and/or you don't want to DIY this, then a plumber is the way to go. There are fairly easy ways to DIY fix or replace the valve. You can start a new question asking how to fix the valve, with some pictures of the valve and surrounding area.
